# How to print values from String[][] to JSP using JSTL tags?

Tags: jsp, servlets, jstl

I`got confused with the problem of how to print instances of a two dimensional string array in JSP page using JSTL tags...
One string array consists of 50 other string array that consist 4 String data types.

```
String[][] messages = new String[50][4]
```

I am forwarding that array to a JSP page that use JSTL tags `<c:forEach></c:forEach>` to list the array.

```
<c:forEach items="${messages}" var="inbox">
    <c:forEach items="${inbox}" var="data">
        <c:out value="${data}"></c:out>
    </c:forEach>
</c:forEach>
```

But the output is: 131002 Example Hello World!  Default Default 27/07/2017 19:44:22 NEW
I tried to add indexes to c:out -> `<c:out value=${data[0]}></c:out>`, but it didn`t work..

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you tried using indexes but this will work fine:

```
<c:forEach items="${messages}" var="inbox">
    <c:out value="${inbox[0]}"></c:out>
    <c:out value="${inbox[1]}"></c:out>
    ...
</c:forEach>
```

`data[0]` is invalid because `data` is not an array.